# x11: Is there anyway to know which URL is browsing, from a browser window id?

Tags: ubuntu, browser, window, x11

Is there anyway to know which URL is browsing, from a browser window id. I'm working on Ubuntu system with X window system. I'm new to X window programming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theoretically you could get the text out of a browser by finding the particular xwindow its in, as all xwindows are completely accessible by all other xwindows, you would be driving down a deep dark path into X internals.  Trust me, it's a mess in there.

The easier way would be to see if the browser has an API that allows you access to those pieces of information.  I'm pretty sure that anything based on QTs/webkit will allow this (Chrome, Safari, Konqueror), and I believe that FF has this functionality as well.  Alternatively you could route requests through a proxy and capture the data there.

So, the short answer is yes, you can do it by trolling through XWindows and XAtoms, but there are far easier ways to gather that info.